# jQuery appear loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Explanation

I'm struggling in order to make this [jquery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) plugin work "out of a loop". As you can see in the example below, every time I scroll down, the plugin its triggered. Is there any way to trigger it only once?

### Code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".end").appear();
    $(".end").on("appear", function() {
        console.log('triggered');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>appear</title>

        <!-- Main jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- jQuery.appear -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js" integrity="sha256-P0hkxI7EdZY/kqz0D1u1XC9fNjaGWlvd/7OWMTwnXhI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Custom -->
        <script src="custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="">
            <p>scroll down</p>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class="end">
            <p>end</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new to it.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve the desired without this plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn your call to `jQuery#on` into `jQuery#one`, which will ensure that your handler executes ["at most once per element per event type."](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".end").appear();

    $(".end").one("appear", function handler() {
        console.log('triggered');
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>appear</title>

        <!-- Main jQuery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- jQuery.appear -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js" integrity="sha256-P0hkxI7EdZY/kqz0D1u1XC9fNjaGWlvd/7OWMTwnXhI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Custom -->
        <script src="custom.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="">
            <p>scroll down</p>
        </div>

        <div class="">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>

        <div class="end">
            <p>end</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it from the DOM tree 
So you don't have to worry about the element triggering the event again

```
$(".end").appear(); 
$(".end").on("appear", function() {
    console.log('triggered');
    $(".end").remove();
});
```